# Adding One CoreData List to Another

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, merge

Let's say there are two favorite food lists: Johnny's List and Jane's List. They are both in CoreData, are separate entities, but have identical attributes. Both have four attributes: food name, secret ingredient, rating, and where to get it.

The user taps a button to merge the two lists. Specifically, Jane's list should now show up in Johnny's BUT her items should go first.

**A very simple example set of lists:**

**Pre Merge - Johnny's List (only has 1 record)**

Apple Pie -
Apples - 
4.5 - 
Susan's Diner

**Pre Merge - Jane's List (has 2 records)**

Turkey Dinner - 
Turkey - 
5.0 - 
Mom's house -

BBQ Dinner - 
Pulled Pork - 
4.0 - 
Route 6 Rib Shack

**Post Merge - Johnny's List (has 3 records)**

Turkey Dinner - 
Turkey - 
5.0 - 
Mom's house

BBQ Dinner - 
Pulled Pork - 
4.0 - 
Route 6 Rib Shack

Apple Pie - 
Apples - 
4.5 - 
Susan's Diner

Johnny's new list of 3 items should save over Johnny's old list in CoreData. Jane's list should be cleared.

Comment: where do you want to save the merged data ?

Comment: Into CoreData again. Both lists already exist in CoreData as separate entities. This function should take list B, add it to list A, save the new list A to core data, and then clear list B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

There are likely several ways to solve this question but what I received for answers and found online weren't doing the trick. I took a shot at just writing the code and it works!

**My Code**

Here's my merge function.

- It is passed only one parameter: the destination name. That is because my source list context was already setup outside the function.
- Alternatively you could pass two parameters, the name of List A and List B, and set both contexts up in the function.
- My CoreData fetch also has a sort predicate which you might not need.

  ```
  func merge_ListA_Into_ListB (targetList: String) {
  //Setup Targetlist context
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

  //Get sorted CoreData list and assign it to targetList_Cntxt
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: targetList)
  let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "displayOrder", ascending: true)
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ sortDescriptor ]
  do {
      let fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]

      if let results = fetchedResults {
          targetList_Cntxt = results
      }
  } catch { print(error)  }

  for i in (0..<listA_Cntxt.count).reverse() {
      //Grab a ListA task item
      let itemToMove = listA_Cntxt[i]

      //Assign the ListA item's contents to variables
      let nameToTransfer = itemToMove.valueForKey("name") as? String
      let descToTransfer = itemToMove.valueForKey("desc") as? String
      //Assign the ListA item's contents to the target's object
      let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(targetList, inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
      newItem.setValue(nameToTransfer, forKey: "name")
      newItem.setValue(descToTransfer, forKey: "desc")

      //Insert the item!!
      targetList_Cntxt.insert(newItem, atIndex: 0)
  }

  //Calls function that updates each records sort/display #
  update_TargetDisplayOrder()
  try! managedContext.save()
  print("List merged into \(targetList).")
  ```

  }

Good luck!